# What are the inputs x for each timestep t?

Tags: neural-networks, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, seq2seq

I am currently having little understanding problems with seq2seq Models that are using LSTM. When I look at this image of a normal LSTM-Cell: [image]
According to my information, these cells exist in the Encoder and in the Decoder. But:

How would the Encoder (if the cell is part of the encoder) train the weights applied to the inputs inside them, when it does not make predictions or in general computes loss?

And if it would be part of the Decoder: Where would it get the xs. Or are the xs simply the same that are put into the Encoder?

Because I thought, that the Encoder would get the inputs, make some hidden state and cell state of it (using LSTM) and give it to the Decoder. But obviously the Decoder takes other inputs, too. You may see that the question is not single one, but I think it can take a single answer, since I think I did not understand the structure correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll explain this in the case of a standard LSTM language model. The task is to predict the next symbol (either a word or a character) given the previous symbols. When the input is `The quick brown`, we want the network to predict `fox` for a word-level model. When the input is `T h e <space> q u i c k <space> b r o w n <space>`, we want the network to predict `f`.

The outline of this network is

- Embedding (input has dimension $p_0$, output has dimension $p_1$)
- Linear layer (output has dimension $p_2$)
- LSTM layers (output has dimension $p_2$)
- Linear layer (output has dimension $p_0$)
- Softmax  (output has dimension $p_0$)

I'll explain each part in more detail.
So for the input `The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog`, we embed each of the words using either a pre-trained embedding or an embedding that we train ourselves. This gives vectors $v_\text{the}, v_\text{quick}, v_\text{brown}, \dots v_\text{dog}$. Each of the $v_i$ has dimension $p_1$.

The core of the LSTM language model is 1 or more LSTM layers with dimension $p_2$. In general, $p_1\neq p_2$, so whenever this is the case, we can put a linear layer between the embedding and LSTM layers so that the input is the appropriate size.

The LSTM prediction is based on three inputs: $x(t), c(t-1), h(t-1)$. The $c$ and $h$ are created recursively by the LSTM. The $x(t)$ contains the embedding, optionally transformed by the linear layer.

In the language model, the $c$ values are only used by the LSTM to predict the next step in the sequence. The $h$ values are the LSTM's "predictions" for the next token in the sequence. Because the $h$ values might not have the same dimension as the vocabulary, there's usually a linear layer to project $h$ with dimension $p_2$ to the vocabulary dimension $p_3$.

---

> How would the Encoder (if the cell is part of the encoder) train the weights applied to the inputs inside them, when it does not make predictions or in general computes loss?

The LSTM does make "predictions," in a loose sense -- it produces vectors with size $p_2$, which might need to be projected to size $p_0$.

The predictions are $h$. The weights are updated using [backpropagation](/questions/tagged/backpropagation).

> And if it would be part of the Decoder: Where would it get the xs. Or are the xs simply the same that are put into the Encoder?

The $x$ values are the inputs to the layer, so the $x$ values come from you, the person who programmed the network. In this example, the $x$ values come from the embedding.

Comment: Thanks, that was very helpful! But: The inputs are changed somehow (its shape) but... you cant just change it's shape, can you? So how are they changed? I heard often about some kind of representation of words where there is a vector with different values discribing the attributes from the word, but that is something very different, right?

Comment: Or maybe... I understood this wrong and by embedding you mean just one-hot encoded, so the inputs aren't changed. Whats right?

Comment: An embedding is just a lookup table that maps a word to a vector. It’s the same as a one-hot-encoding followed by a linear layer.

Comment: So the only thing that the Encoder is doing is producing the cell state, hidden state and converting the input to one-hot encodings?

Comment: This model architecture is outlined in five bullets. I suppose you can label some of the bullets “encoder,” but of different models will label different things as encoders. Not sure what great insight you’re looking for with this.

Comment: I just don't know. It is so hard to understand to me, cause I am new. I try to ask my questions as specific as I can, but you see, I am still struggling and trying to improve things. But I want to understand these things so I am gonna keep trying, so:

as I understood, the Encoder embeds inputs -> converts them to one-hot encodings; these one-hot encodings are inputs (x(t)) for the LSTM-Cells as you wrote. But I must have understand this wrong: why would we have to train an embedding for one-hot encoding?

Comment: Suppose $u$ is a one-hot vector with dimension $p_0$ and $X$ is a $p_1 \times p_0$ matrix. The embedding of $u$ is given as $Xu=v$. You need to train $X$ to find a good embedding for each of your tokens. An "embedding layer" still trains $X$, but instead of using one-hot vectors, you give it an integer for the index that takes the value 1. This is more efficient because you don't have to do a bunch of arithmetic.

Comment: ... so the place for the 1 of the one-hot encodings is tweaked?

Comment: As I said, $X$ is trained. Not $u$.

Comment: Ah...ok, so in my words: The embedding layer takes one-hot encoded vector dimensionality p0, applies matrix X (dimensionality p0 * p1) to it, and what comes out is vector of dimensionality p1 containing ... what? Another one-hot encoded vector, but a more suitable?

Comment: No, $v$ is not a one-hot vector, it's a dense vector. That's the reason to use embeddings: dense vectors give continuous-valued representations, and these representations tend to work better for neural networks.

Comment: So the embedding layer learns to give a meaningful representation (dense vector) of its input (one-hot vector), right?

Comment: Ok. In the model of this only course there is only an Input and LSTM-Layer as Encoder:
   `encoder_inputs = Input(shape=(None, num_encoder_tokens))
    encoder_lstm = LSTM(latent_dim, return_state=True)
    encoder_outputs, state_hidden, state_cell = encoder_lstm(encoder_inputs)`